# Applet wont initialize, but needs to be abstract

Tags: java, applet, initialization, abstract, minesweeper

Trying to get minesweeper to work with right clicks, everything worked up to this point;

Discovered that i needed to use MouseListener....which seems to be fine but my main error is I cannot get the applet to initialize and dont understand why. I read this but could not understand the soloution: 
[Abstract Class Error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800659/abstract-class-error-in-java)

Any help would be appreciated, I know that the error stems from being an abstract class but without it the applet wont run.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

abstract class Minesweeper extends Applet implements MouseListener{
// initializing all data types
JButton[] a; // The grid boxes
int counter = 1; // Obsolete
char[] letter; // Array of mine locations
int[] numbers; // Array of numbers; values and locations
boolean explode = false;
String name1;
String name2;
int mines;


public void init() {
    // The code below initializes and locates the grid
    a = new JButton[100];
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    // The code below fills the grid with buttons that can be clicked

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        a[counter] = new JButton();
        a[counter].setText(" ");
        a[counter].setBackground(Color.white);
        a[counter].addMouseListener(this);
        add(a[counter]);
    }
            numbers = new int[100];
    letter = new char[100];
    for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
        mines = (int) (Math.random() * 100); 
        if (letter[mines] == '*') {
            counter--;
        } else {
            letter[mines] = '*';
        }
    } 

    for (counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        numbers[counter] = 0;
    }

    for (int search = 0; search < 10; search++) {
        for (int searchb = 0; searchb < 10; searchb++) {
            if (letter[search * 10 + searchb] == '*') {
                if (search != 0) {
                    numbers[((search - 1) * 10) + searchb]++;
                }
                if (search != 9) {
                    numbers[((search + 1) * 10) + searchb]++;
                }
                if (searchb != 0) {
                    numbers[((search * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                }
                if (searchb != 9) {
                    numbers[((search * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 0) && (searchb != 0)) {
                    numbers[(((search - 1) * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 9) && (searchb != 9)) {
                    numbers[(((search + 1) * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 0) && (searchb != 9)) {
                    numbers[(((search - 1) * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 9) && (searchb != 0)) {
                    numbers[(((search + 1) * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                }

            }

        }

    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        if(letter[counter]!= '*')
        letter[counter] = (char) ('0' + numbers[counter]);
    }
}



// ActionEvent e is the click
public void clickPerformed(MouseEvent e) {
    int pickedsquare = 0, WinCheck=1, pickedcolumn = 0;
    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    counter++;
    b.setText("Test");
    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){
         for (int f = 0; f < 100; f++) {
        if (a[f].getText() == "Test") {
            pickedsquare = f;
            name1=" "+letter[f];
            a[f].setBackground(Color.red);
            break;
          }
        }
    }

    else{
        for (int f = 0; f < 100; f++) {
            if (a[f].getText() == "Test") {
            pickedsquare = f;
            name1=" "+letter[f];
            a[f].setText(name1);
            a[f].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            if(a[f].getText()=="0")
                a[f].setText(" ");
            break;
          }
      }
      if (letter[pickedsquare] == '*')
        explode = true;

      if (explode == true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are dead!");
          for (int counterb = 0; counterb <= 99; counterb++) {
            a[counterb].setEnabled(false);

          }
      }
    WinCheck=1;
      for(int g=0;g<100;g++){
          if(a[g].getBackground()!=Color.lightGray){
              if(letter[g]!='*'){
                WinCheck=0;
                break;
              }
          }
      }
      if (WinCheck==1) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have swept all mines!");
          for (int counterb = 0; counterb <= 99; counterb++) {
            a[counterb].setEnabled(false);

          }
      }
   }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an abstract class without implementation of it. If you make the class a concrete class and add the missing methods then it will run without any errors.
here is the fixed code , you still have to work on it though to make fully functional:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Minesweeper extends Applet implements MouseListener{
// initializing all data types
JButton[] a; // The grid boxes
int counter = 1; // Obsolete
char[] letter; // Array of mine locations
int[] numbers; // Array of numbers; values and locations
boolean explode = false;
String name1;
String name2;
int mines;


public void init() {
    // The code below initializes and locates the grid
    a = new JButton[100];
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    // The code below fills the grid with buttons that can be clicked

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        a[counter] = new JButton();
        a[counter].setText(" ");
        a[counter].setBackground(Color.white);
        a[counter].addMouseListener(this);
        add(a[counter]);
    }
            numbers = new int[100];
    letter = new char[100];
    for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
        mines = (int) (Math.random() * 100); 
        if (letter[mines] == '*') {
            counter--;
        } else {
            letter[mines] = '*';
        }
    } 

    for (counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        numbers[counter] = 0;
    }

    for (int search = 0; search < 10; search++) {
        for (int searchb = 0; searchb < 10; searchb++) {
            if (letter[search * 10 + searchb] == '*') {
                if (search != 0) {
                    numbers[((search - 1) * 10) + searchb]++;
                }
                if (search != 9) {
                    numbers[((search + 1) * 10) + searchb]++;
                }
                if (searchb != 0) {
                    numbers[((search * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                }
                if (searchb != 9) {
                    numbers[((search * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 0) && (searchb != 0)) {
                    numbers[(((search - 1) * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 9) && (searchb != 9)) {
                    numbers[(((search + 1) * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 0) && (searchb != 9)) {
                    numbers[(((search - 1) * 10) + searchb) + 1]++;
                }
                if ((search != 9) && (searchb != 0)) {
                    numbers[(((search + 1) * 10) + searchb) - 1]++;
                }

            }

        }

    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        if(letter[counter]!= '*')
        letter[counter] = (char) ('0' + numbers[counter]);
    }
}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```